# What are the things that thread doesn’t share with process?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have couple of doubts regarding the process and threads and are given below

1.What are the things that thread doesn’t share with process?

2.Why there is separate stack for each thread?

3.How do two threads from different process communicate?

Comment: do your homework yourself or flag your question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is a definition. You don't need "help" with this one, you need a "book."

2) I'm very willing to help this one. It isn't a simple definition question, so let's start by answering your question with a question... In a single-process, single-thread system, what is the purpose of the stack? Once you can answer this, you are an inch from answering this question.

3) On what system?

Comment: Stack are generally used to store local variables and function arguments ,Am I right?

Comment: You are correct, but that's in addition to some other important things. What happens on a single process, single thread system when I am in one function and I call another function? Does anything special happen regarding the execution context of the old function?

Comment: Yes there happens context switching ,I mean context of current process gets stored on stack and context of some other process gets poped up from stack

Comment: Getting closer..  San was hinting at return adresses - another vital use for the hardware stack.  On non-trival OS, context-changes take place between threads.  A process context swap only occurs if newly-running thread and the preempted thread belong to different processes.  As others have posted, you need to get the differences between processes and threads sorted out first - get a book 'Operating System Fundamentals' or some such like.

Comment: That's correct, but remember we're talking about a single-process, single-thread system right now. Pretend there's no OS. What happens when I call function B() from function A()? What steps are taken on the processor? When function B() is done executing, how do we know where to go next?

Comment: When function B() is called its context are pushed on stack also address of the next instruction in function A() is gets stored in PC.When B() is done vaule from PC Is fetched so as we run next instruction A().

Comment: Ok. So now that we have this mechanism working for one system, what happens when we have multiple process? If process A wants needs a stack to store function call context state in addition to local variables, what does process B do since it also needs a stack? If they share the same stack, they would clobber each other's context information. How is this problem solved?

Comment: Need to have separate stack for each threads,got my answer @SanJacinto.Thanks you very much .

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

Wikipedia is down for the moment, butafter that, you can check it :)

Your second question actually answers your first. Threads work at a different rate from one another. Imagine a program being 1 line of commands all following eachother, waiting for completion of one another. Now add a second line so you have 2 bits of processing done at the same time (and different rates of speed quite possibly). That's a thread.

In essence, a thread is a different process, spawned from a mutual application. Usability varies greatly according to which system you use and what you wist to accomplish.

These are the types of things you're better off using Google that Stackoverflow.